# How can I use the output sound from GarageBand as my 'mic' for Skype or similar?

Tags: macos, audio, garageband

I run GarageBand on my MacMini with a simple USB audio interface. I want to be able to play my electric guitar through GarageBAnd so the sound with SFX is what is fed into Skype and other video chat sites, as if this were my microphone.

But I think selecting the USB device as my audio input will give me only the dry sound from my instrument, not the modified sound from Garageband?
So how can I do what I want without expensive equipment?

I have realised my USB interface has a mixer inputs/playback which means through headphones I can choose to select only the processed output from GarageBand if I set the interface as my audio-out... but how do I get that back into the Mac short of putting a cable from the headphone-out => Mac line-in?!

Comment: Have a look at [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) which is a modern Soundflower replacement. \[I've never used it, I use [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) which is a brilliant, but paid, alternative\]

Comment: That sounds neat, though in that context the ideal would be to set AH as a "virtual audio input" so other apps could treat it as such without knowing it's even running?

Comment: But it sounds quite a general solution, I had the ideas DAWs could sort of do this anyway to chain apps together?

Comment: Though it seems my "virtual device" is what SoundFlower does": https://iandunn.name/2017/04/04/recording-skype-and-a-mic-on-separate-tracks-in-garageband/

Answer (score 2):

I just used the [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole).‌ It worked perfectly.

At the very high level you have to do these things:

Follow these [screenshots and steps](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole/wiki/Multi-Output-Device) to:

- Add blackhole to your OS. It's not an app you install. It's a package. Once you install it. This creates a new audio device ie adds an item named *blackhole* to the list of your audio inputs and outputs.
- Create a Multi-output device (I did blackhole + Headphone) using your Mac's Utilities.

Then

- In *Garageband* you set your *output* to that blackhole (not Multi-output)
- In *Skype* your set your Mic *input* to that blackhole (not Multi-output)
- Done! Begin speaking into your primary audio input source (I used my Mac's microphone)

All the steps are mentioned in detail [here](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole#record-system-audio). Garageband is the 'sending application'. Skype is the 'receiving application'

**The end result for me looked like like:**

Create new project:

[image]

GarageBand Settings

[image]

---

I've also been told that you can achieve the same using the [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) app.

btw, everything I mentioned in my answer is **free**.

Comment: was trying this out with Zoom and airpods, I did the same, garageband can play to the other person, but then my voice via the airpods mic doesn't go through. Do I need an aggregate device for this??

Comment: Did you see [these](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole/wiki/Multi-Output-Device) steps? I only created a multiOutput device. Your should have something like [this](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole/raw/master/Images/Multi-Output/5.png). Where you have a Blackhole device AND multi-output device (which is a combo of blackhole device + another physical). I made my combo with the Airpods because I wanted to use my mac's mic as my input. If this doesn't work then open a question (and share it) with screenshots of your OS devices, garageband input/outputs + zoom's input/output

Comment: I managed to get mic through to zoom with a new voice track and turning on monitoring. Is that how you do it as well?

Comment: I don't know what "new voice track means" Can you share a screenshot? For zoom ie receiving application the audio input should be set to the multipoutput device you've created yourself

Comment: I am using Scarlett 2i2 interface. I set GarageBand to output to MultiOutDevice, then I set the Zoom input to Blackhole. With this, the other side can hear the sound when I playback from GarageBand, but she cannot hear my voice. I figure that what the multioutdevice does is just to send the output to blackhole (and to zoom), and also to my headphones, but it does nothing to the inputs. So what I need to do is, I create a new track in GarageBand, then I set it to monitoring, screenshot here https://imgur.com/a/Gu1ou2q, with this, then she can hear both the GarageBand and my voice.

Comment: Great that it’s working now